# Assign a value base on a comparison between a row and another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], "B": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
df

    A   B
0   1   100
1   2   200
2   3   300
3   1   400
4   2   500
5   3   600
```

For each row I need to populate a column C where I get the value of "B" for the previous row having the same value in "A".

Comment: What would be the output, not in words but in an actual DataFrame

Comment: `df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].shift()`.